# Как работает CancellationToken в TaskFactory.StartNew Method (Action, CancellationToken)?

Tags: c#, .net, task

Делаю:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>Method(),ct)
```

В другом месте вызываю `tokenSource.Cancel();`, но ничего не происходит.

Мне казалось, что такая перегрузка должна полностью задачу снимать.

Получается, что нужно токен передавать непосредственно в сам метод и там производить анализ?

Можно ли как-нибудь отменить задачу, непередавая во внутрь токен?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Смотрите.

Вы не можете «отменить» уже бегущий код — по тем же причинам, по которым вы не можете «убить» бегущий thread. Поэтому код, запускаемый через `Task.Run`, добежит до конца, если только он сам не будет анализировать токен и не отменит себя сам.

Однако, таск не будет *запущен*, если токен находится *уже* в отменённом состоянии. Поскольку запуск `Task`'а — расходная штука, это неплохая оптимизация.

Кроме того, таск при этом будет *ассоциирован* с этим токеном, и если код в `Method` бросит исключение через `token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested`, это исключение будет считаться относящимся к таску. Тем самым таск будет завершён в состоянии `Cancelled`, а не `Faulted`.

Источник информации: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c2f614f6-c96c-4821-84cc-050b21aaee45/taskfactorystartnew-cancellation-token-parameter?forum=parallelextensions

---

Воспроизводящий пример:

```
async Task Run()
{
    var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var ct = cts.Token;
    var t = Task.Run((Action)(() => // каст нужен! пояснение в конце ответа
        {
            while (true)
            {
                ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                Thread.Sleep(200);
            }
        }), cts.Token);
    await Task.Delay(400);
    cts.Cancel();
    try
    {
        await t;
    }
    catch (TaskCanceledException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"caught TaskCanceledException, task status = {t.Status}");
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"caught OperationCanceledException, task status = {t.Status}");
    }
}
```

Этот код попадает в `catch (OperationCanceledException ex)`, и состояние таска — `Canceled`. А если убрать токен, то мы попадаем также в `catch (OperationCanceledException ex)`, но состояние — `Faulted`. В этом случае рантайм считает, что произошла не отмена таска, а просто какое-то постороннее исключение.

(В `TaskCanceledException` мы попадаем, если таск был отменён до запуска.)

---

(Ошибка в предыдущей версии кода была в том, что не было явного приведения к `Action` [которое практически никогда не нужно!], и ввиду бесконечного цикла внутри типовыводитель не мог решить, это [перегрузка с `Action`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160373(v=vs.110).aspx) или [перегрузка с `Func<Task>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194916(v=vs.110).aspx)! В результате он выбирал не то, что нужно, и рантайм считал, что отменён не таск, а процесс его создания.)

Comment: Отличие связано с тем, что при передаче задаче токена она *сразу же* переходит в состояние Canceled, не дожидаясь завершения кода. Это можно заметить переставив исключение и задержку - или посмотрев на стектрейс.

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Тьфу, и правда, таск же не успевает запуститься! Спасибо!

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Хм, всё равно не получается привести в состояние Faulted. Странно.

Comment: тьфу, спасибо, и правда - если задача успела запуститься, то окончания она дождется...

Comment: `OperationCanceledException` воспринимается как отмена задачи. Ничего странного.

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Но документация и Stephen Toub говорят, кажется, обратное. Если я правильно понял процитированный в ответе текст.

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Из текста по ссылке на MSDN: If the token's IsCancellationRequested property returns false or if the exception's token does not match the Task's token, the OperationCanceledException is treated like a normal exception, causing the Task to transition to the Faulted state.

Comment: Ага, я тоже нашел этот фрагмент. Ну, как всегда, обманули :)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51513/discussion-between-vladd-and-pavel-mayorov).

Answer (score 6):

Да, токен необходимо передавать в метод, и там периодически вызывать `ThrowIfCancellationRequested()`. Однако, это не отменяет необходимости передавать его вторым параметром `StartNew()`. Это делается на тот случай, если отмена операции запрошена раньше чем начал выполняться ваш метод (а так же для того, чтобы связать таск с токеном). Примерно так:

```
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        while (true)
        {
            cts.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            Console.WriteLine("I'm working...");
        }
    }, cts.Token);

cts.CancelAfter(10);
```

Если была запрошена отмена, то метод `ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` кинет `OperationCanceledException`. При желании, его можно поймать и сообщить юзеру, что операция успешно отменена, например.

Если хочется, то можно обходиться без эксепшена, а просто в методе проверять:

```
if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
{
    /*выходим из метода*/
}
```

Но тогда сама задача не будет знать о том, что её отменили. В свойстве `Status` у неё будет `TaskStatus.RanToCompletion` вместо `TaskStatus.Canceled`.

UPD: Дополнительный материал по теме: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997396(v=vs.110).aspx