# Ограничить время жизни потока

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

Есть список задач, каждую задачу нужно ограничить по времени. Если задача не успевает выполниться, то пусть возвращается какое-то дефолтное значение.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();

        foreach (var i in GetInts())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("result: " + i);
        }

        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("done " + sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds.ToString("F2"));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static List<int> GetInts()
    {
        using (var cts = new CancellationTokenSource())
        {
            var tasks = new Task<int>[3];

            tasks[1] = Task.Run(() =>
            {
                int i = 5000;
                Thread.Sleep(i);
                Console.WriteLine(i);
                return i;
            }, cts.Token);


            tasks[0] = Task.Run(() =>
            {
                int i = 3000;
                Thread.Sleep(i);
                Console.WriteLine(i);
                return i;
            }, cts.Token);

            tasks[2] = Task.Run(() =>
            {
                int i = 2000;
                Thread.Sleep(i);
                Console.WriteLine(i);
                return i;
            }, cts.Token);

            var delay = 1000;

            return tasks.Select(x => x.TimeoutAfter(delay, cts)).Select(x => x.Result).ToList();
        }
    }
}

public static class TaskExtensions
{
    public static async Task<TResult> TimeoutAfter<TResult>(this Task<TResult> task, int delay, CancellationTokenSource cts)
    {

        using (var timeoutCancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource())
        {

            var completedTask = await Task.WhenAny(task, Task.Delay(delay, timeoutCancellationTokenSource.Token));
            if (completedTask == task)
            {
                timeoutCancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
                return await task;
            }
            else
            {
                cts.Cancel();
                return default(TResult);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Хотя в коде прописано ограничение в 1000мс, данный код выводит следующий результат:

```
2000
result: 0
result: 0
result: 2000
done 2010,83
3000
5000
```

Почему задача с 2с попадает в result? А если выставить delay = 3000, то выведутся все задачи (хотя 5с не должна):

```
2000
3000
5000
result: 3000
result: 5000
result: 2000
done 5008,06
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Смотрите. Вы не можете завершить бегущую задачу насильно, точно так же как вы не можете завершить насильно любой другой код. Для этого задача должна сотрудничать.

Идея с использованием `CancellationToken`'а правильная, но не доведена до конца, отсюда и проблема. `CancellationToken` в `Task.Run` относится только к процессу *запуска* таска*. Когда таск запущен, он не сможет магическим образом узнать о том, что токен сработал, ему нужно самому проверять отмену токена.

Например, так:

```
var ct = cts.Token;
tasks[0] = Task.Run(async () => // добавил async
{
    int i = 3000;
    await Task.Delay(i, ct); // проверяем токен
    Console.WriteLine(i);
    return i;
}, ct);
```

Ещё по теме: [Как работает CancellationToken в TaskFactory.StartNew Method (Action, CancellationToken)?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/612940/10105)

---

*Почти. Ещё он *ассоциируется* с таском, и при выбросе исключения этим токеном таск переходит в состояние `Cancelled`, а не `Faulted`.