# Отменить Task в C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, task

Использую WPF с MVVM паттерном, нажатием на одну кнопку запускаю таскфактори, который делает некую работу, нажатием на Stop, нужно прекратить работу таска. делаю примерно так, но нажатие на стоп не работает, что я делаю не так?

```
var tokerSourse = new CancellationTokenSource();    
StartCommand = new RelayCommand(() => Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Work(), tokerSourse.Token));
StopCommand = new RelayCommand(() => tokerSourse.Cancel());
```

Comment: Таск не прекратится магическим образом просто потому, что вы передали в него токен отмены. Вам надо учитывать этот токен отмены в своем алгоритме и проверять, была ли отменена операция, и если да, то самому завершать алгоритм

Comment: [Подробнее ищите тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/612953/179763)